# typeinitialization exception when trying to build Autodesk Forge .net SDK sample

Tags: .net, autodesk-forge

I am trying to build the simple-csharp sample in Autodesk Forge .net SDK and getting a **" type initialization exception"**.

Does anyone know how to fix this? It seems to be happening when this is called:

> private static BucketsApi bucketsApi =new BucketsApi ();

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because you are declaring as a `static` variable on your class. Please note that static means that will be shared across users on your app, which can potentially leak information.

Take a look [at this sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-WebAPI-sample/blob/master/ASPNET.webapi/Controllers/BucketsController.cs#L49), it shows a similar implementation in C#.

**EDIT**

Please use **RestSharp** `v105.*` for Autodesk.Forge package (as of Feb/2018)